How to get requests from iframes in Chrome extension using chrome debugger
I'm writing Chtome extension which uses Chrome debugger and collects requests and responses where status code was >= 400.
I'm using tabs API to get active tab and attach debugger to it
chrome.debugger.attach({ tabId: tabId }, "1.3", () => {...})
and later in the code I'm listening for events:

chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener((source, method, params) => {

    if (method === "Network.requestWillBeSent") {...})

but it looks that I can capture only requests sent in the context of active tab, but if the tab will have iframes, debugger will not capture that events.
I tried to use code from
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/debugger#attach_to_related_targets before calling
chrome.debugger.attach
but probably doing something wrong as still can't catch iframe requests.
I'm not sure if I'm correctly attaching  child sessions or issue is in the something else. Would be very grateful for any suggestion.
Expecting to catch events when iframe on tab with attached debugger sends request.

Auto-attaching to related targets doesn't work, IIRC, it's a bug, see https://crbug.com. You can try getting the frames manually via Target.getTargets command or chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames API and then attach to each one explicitly.

Thank you for your reply! I tried to collect all frames and now I have their frameIds.
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener((details) => {
  if (details.frameType === "sub_frame" && details.documentLifecycle === "active") {
    pageFrames[details.frameId] = {
      tabId: details.tabId,
      documentId: details.documentId
    }
  }
});

Am I write thinking that now I need to use chrome.debugger.attach and attach to collected frameIds? I'm not really sure because attach expected to have Debugee as a target and I'm not sure if frame's documentId will work.

Looks like Target.getTargets may be the only solution.

@woxxom, thank you very much. Actually chrome.debugger.getTargets was a solution.
I iterated through all available targets and attached to necessary using
chrome.debugger.attach({ targetId: target.id }, "1.3", () => {chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ targetId: target.id }, "Network.enable", {}, () => {});});

It'd be helpful for posterity if you post it as an answer.

So, the problem was solved by attaching all possible targets. The only problem is that you might need to know URL of frame which you would like attach to. Hope that it will be usefull for someone.
// To keep track of attached iframes. Use it later to detach
let iframes = {};
let debuggerAttached = false;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request) {
    // I'm sending "getHar" message to capturing requests/responses
    if (request.message === "getHar") {

        // Sending active Tab ID along the message 
        tabId = request.tabId;
        if (!debuggerAttached) {
          debuggerAttached = true;
          chrome.debugger.getTargets((targets) => {
            if (targets) {
              for (let target of targets) {
                if (target.url.includes("URL_WHICH_YOU_MIGHT_WANT_TO_TRACK")) {
                  iframes[target.id] = target;
                  chrome.debugger.attach({ targetId: target.id }, "1.3", () => {
                    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                      console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                      return;
                    }
                    chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ targetId: target.id }, "Network.enable", {}, () => {});
                  });
                }
              }
            }
          });

            chrome.debugger.attach({ tabId: tabId }, "1.3", () => {
              if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                return;
              }
              chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: tabId }, "Network.enable", {}, () => {});
              // My function which I use to collect requests
              captureHAR(tabId);
            });
          } else {
            // My function which I use to detach from targets
            saveAndDetach(tabId);
          }
    }
});

